# EditorForModel not working in EditorTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I don't know if this is by design or not. But if it's by design, it's so inconsistent.

The `EditorForModel` works for the root `PageModel`, like this:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel, IUsersSelection {
    public IEnumerable<int> UserIds {get;set;}
    public MyEditModel EditModel {get;set;}
    //...
}
public interface IUsersSelection {
    IEnumerable<int> UserIds {get;set;}
}
```

I have an `EditorTemplate` for `IUsersSelection` (named `UsersSelection.cshtml`) like this:

```
@model IUsersSelection
@Html.EditorFor(e => e.UserIds)
```

And in the `MyPage.cshtml`, I use `EditorForModel` like this:

```
@model MyPageModel
<!-- use explicit template name because the model Type does not exactly match -->
<!-- this works fine -->
@Html.EditorForModel("UsersSelection")
```

**The `EditorForModel` above works just fine.**

But now I have another `EditorTemplate` targeting another model, name it `MyEditModel`:

```
public class MyEditModel : IUsersSelection {
    public IEnumerable<int> UserIds {get;set;}
}
```

Its `EditorTemplate` looks like this:

```
@model MyEditModel
@Html.EditorForModel("UsersSelection")
```

Now in my `MyPage.cshtml`, I also have this:

```
@model MyPageModel
<!-- this renders nothing -->
@Html.EditorFor(e => e.EditModel)
```

**The `EditorForModel` in the editor template for `MyEditModel` does not work.**

Do you have any idea on what could be wrong? Or it's just by design (the `EditForModel` works only for interface if it's used for the root PageModel, but not for editor template's model).

**UPDATE**:

Looks like the `EditorForModel` does not work inside editor template at all (no matter the model is interface or not). This may be by design, but look at how I use the interface, this limitation is a bit inconvenient. Now I have to expose a property on the main model for the interface model, like this:

```
 public class UsersSelection : IUsersSelection {
 }

 public class MyEditModel {
     //this does not look neat as the original (desired) model
     public UsersSelection UsersSelection {get; set;}
 }

 //in the editor template for `MyEditModel`
 @Html.EditorFor(e => e.UsersSelection, "UsersSelection")
```

I've found out that the `EditorForModel` does not work for the same model instance with the current editor template's model. The following model works:

```
 public class MyEditModel : IUsersSelection {
     public IUsersSelection UsersSelection {get; set;}
 }
```

But the following won't (because `UsersSelection` set to the same model instance of `MyEditModel`):

```
public class MyEditModel : IUsersSelection {
     public MyEditModel(){
         UsersSelection = this;
     }
     public IUsersSelection UsersSelection {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to follow what classes/models you have and what you have not, and also which properties exists and which doesn't. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a clear [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616).

Comment: @Progman it's so strange that you don't see my model classes in my question. I have just 3 classes/interfaces involved here: `MyEditModel`, `IUsersSelection` and finally `MyPageModel`. Do you see them all in my question? The issue is just simple as what I described. You can **surely** reproduce it if you try it yourself. The question may be a bit difficult to understand, but it has all the info needed.

Comment: @Progman if you look at the end of the question (the updated part), I've almost figured it out when it is not working and when it works. But still I don't understand why it should not be working, almost by design, but that design seemingly poses a bit limitation for us to do a fairly good thing.

Comment: @Progman to get started reproducing the issue (for yourself to understand that it's truly existed), just create simple classes/interfaces as I've posted in my question. You need to create an editor template for `MyEditModel` and one more editor template for `IUsersSelection`. All the code for the templates are already posted in my question. In `MyEditModel.cshtml`, you have `@Html.EditorForModel("UsersSelection")`. You have `UsersSelection.cshtml` as editor template for `IUsersSelection` and it can contain anything (for testing). That's just simple like that, you won't see any rendered.